React Native WebView or Custom WebView
I just want to ask a question. I have been playing around with WebView's lately and have issues in integrating the WebView in my React Native App, I have even tried many library's such as:
react-native-pell-rich-editor
react-native-render-html
react-native-htmlview

My WebView's sits inside  a Flat List so I have many WebView's that are rendered inside this list, I was using Scroll View and rendered the WebView's in a Scroll View but had issues when using WebView's this way and using the libraries I have mentioned. When I take out the WebView's and use a Text component, everything works fine but I need to use a WebView to render the html coming back from the server.
So my question is that should I create a Custom WebView natively, using Java as the native language as my React Native app is for Android and using this Custom WebView as a library inside React Native?
I found this link:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/custom-webview-ios

But the tutorial is for IOS, so I'm trying to find an Android Alternative. If someone could point me to the right direction that would be appreciated.

When dealing with multiple WebViews inside a FlatList, performance and compatibility issues can arise.
You can directly use the third party libs:
react-native-webview
This is the best for handling dynamically content in html as well custom html.
Still you like to go with custom webview ?

is it lead any version issue in future ?

Not every time, but it happens by this three cases.

React Native Version Updates.
Library Maintenance
Platform-Specific Changes(Depends Android & IOs)


I have tried React-Native-webview, but still causes the app to crash. The app is 95% finished its just this issue. I'm considering developing the app in android java now. Atleast the backend is complete. I hope I don't come into these issues when developing in java Android by rendering html in androids java webview

But isn't the React-Native-webview already pre installed withe the React-Native project when created

@redoc01 This is the third party libs, you need first install it and configure it. Crash may happens bcz you missed something in configure, I would request to check again.

I followed this resiurce https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md and added android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true, still the crash happens

Have you tried this react-native-webview library in react native?
I can dynamically change many HTML pages and use them with this library. I did not encounter any problems.
Getting Started

I have tried React-Native-webview, but still causes the app to crash. The app is 95% finished its just this issue. I'm considering developing the app in android java now. Atleast the backend is complete. I hope I don't come into these issues when developing in java Android by rendering html in androids java webview
